# Facebook app to manage friends lists

Tags: facebook-apps, friend-list

I never used any app on Facebook, but the current (and previous) page for managing friends is not very useful.

I have some friends (~250) and various lists, with different names and privileges.
I'm looking for an app that:

- shows me all friends without list
- selecting a lists, shows me friends in the selected lists
- easy way to move friends from one list to another

does something similar exist on Facebook???

Answer (score 2):

After some searches I finally found the needed app..

[Friends Manager CRM](https://apps.facebook.com/283318771779450/)

You can:

1. Select one or more than one friends
2. Drag&Drop friends from one list to another
3. Display all friends/ all friends in one particular list / all friends in no list
4. others (read the app description...)

Comment: No longer works after 1st of May 2015.